# Change MediaPlayer URI

Tags: android, uri, media-player

I have the following working code:

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.player);

        videoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        playVideo();

        // video finish listener
        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.start();
                }
        });
    }

    public void playVideo() {
                MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
                videoView.setMediaController(mc);
                videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://sayedhashimi.com/downloads/android/movie.mp4"));
                videoView.requestFocus(); 
        }
```

I just want to change the MediaPlayer data source when the video finishes (setOnCompletionListener).

Answer (score 9):

I'm working on this same issue.  Here is what I've come up with:

```
   public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
       mp.reset();
       mp.setDataSource(this, newUri);
       mp.start();
   }
```

Comment: this will result in: 'start called in state 2'

Comment: I actually have never seen that, are you getting that message in your log?

Comment: yes. calling .prepare() before calling .start() helps. But sometimes I still have random errors like (1, something) or (-38, something). the strange thing is that some times it works and some times it doesn't. More about the strange errors here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839082/android-4-2-with-4-mediaplayers-cant-play-this-video

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```kotlin
mp.release()
mp = createNew(context,newUri)
mp.start()
```

Anything else I tried gave me errors as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869229/change-mediaplayer-uri#:%7E:text=yes.%20calling%20.prepare()%20before%20calling%20.start()%20helps.%20But%20sometimes%20I%20still%20have%20random%20errors%20like%20(1%2C%20something)%20or%20(%2D38%2C%20something).%20the%20strange%20thing%20is%20that%20some%20times%20it%20works%20and%20some%20times%20it%20doesn%27t.%20More%20about%20the%20strange%20errors%20here).
Creating new media player every time won't be that harmful for performance as you will most likely have only one at a time anyway.

hope it helps ; )