# android - error using multiple instance of VideoView

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I want an activity that show two (or more) videoview in a linear layout.

Using videoview with local files as datasource all works fine, but using video by stream rtsp I have a Mediaplayer error code like (1,1), usually the first video show correctly and second show error.

I try the two stream one at time, and they works, so there aren't format errors.

I read something about resource release of mediaplayer ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839082/android-4-2-with-4-mediaplayers-cant-play-this-video)) , but I need that each real-time video are shown.

this is code in my Activity :

```
   try{
    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    Uri video = Uri.parse(urlVideo+"1"); 
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.start();

    videoView2 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView2);
    Uri video2 = Uri.parse(urlVideo+"0");
    videoView2.setVideoURI(video2);
    videoView2.start();
}
catch (Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

and this is the complete error on logcat :

```
    01-14 10:57:26.627: I/Crayon_Player(148): <== setDataSource(rtsp://192.168.4.125:554/0)
01-14 10:57:26.627: V/MediaPlayerService(148): [200] setVideoSurfaceTexture(0x1b808e0)
01-14 10:57:26.627: I/Crayon_Player(148): ==> setVideoSurfaceTexture(0x1b808e0)
01-14 10:57:26.627: I/RTSPEngine(148): @@@VOLOG Info THD 019EBA08:    utility.cpp  MakeLog  990    2419010028 DESCRIBE rtsp://192.168.4.125:554/1 RTSP/1.0

01-14 10:57:26.627: I/RTSPEngine(148): CSeq: 1

01-14 10:57:26.627: I/RTSPEngine(148): Accept: application/sdp

01-14 10:57:26.627: I/RTSPEngine(148): Accept-Encoding: identity

01-14 10:57:26.627: I/RTSPEngine(148): Content-Encoding: identity

01-14 10:57:26.627: I/RTSPEngine(148): Content-Language: en-US

01-14 10:57:26.627: I/RTSPEngine(148): User-Agent: Player/LG Player 1.0 for Android(stagefright alternative)

01-14 10:57:26.627: I/RTSPEngine(148): 

01-14 10:57:26.627: I/RTSPEngine(148): @@@VOLOG Info THD 019EBA08:    utility.cpp  MakeLog  990    2419010028 

01-14 10:57:26.627: I/Crayon_Player(148): <== setVideoSurfaceTexture(0x1b808e0) return=0
01-14 10:57:26.627: V/MediaPlayerService(148): [200] setVideoSurfaceTexture(0x18fb118)
01-14 10:57:26.627: V/MediaPlayerService(148): [200] setAudioStreamType(3)
01-14 10:57:26.627: V/MediaPlayerService(148): [200] prepareAsync
01-14 10:57:26.627: I/Crayon_Player(148): ==> prepareAsync
01-14 10:57:26.627: I/Crayon_Player(148): <== prepareAsync return=0
01-14 10:57:26.627: I/CrayonGraph-PlayerOMX(148): [SetURL] url=rtsp://192.168.4.125:554/0
01-14 10:57:26.627: E/CRTSPSource(148): @@@VOLOG Error THD 019ECCC8:   CRTSPSource.cpp  LoadSource  247    The RTSP Source didn't close correctly!
01-14 10:57:26.627: E/voCOMXFileSource(148): @@@VOLOG Error THD 019ECCC8:   voCOMXFileSource.cpp  LoadFile  1010    m_pSource->LoadSource was failed. 0X80000007
01-14 10:57:26.627: W/CrayonGraph-Base(148): [setParameter] comp=OMX.VisualOn.FileSource, paramIndex=0x100000d, pData=0x1915120, eRet = 0x80001001 
01-14 10:57:26.627: E/CrayonGraph-PlayerOMX(148): [setURI] OMX_IndexParamContentURI fail 1
01-14 10:57:26.627: E/CrayonGraph-PlayerBuilder(148): setURI fail 1
01-14 10:57:26.627: E/Crayon_PlayerEngine(148): ERROR!! notifyListener_l msg[100] ext1[1] ext2[1]
01-14 10:57:26.627: V/MediaPlayerService(148): [200] notify (0x190da70, 100, 1, 1)
01-14 10:57:26.627: E/MediaPlayer(31866): error (1, 1)
```

Comment: I have test this code on my Lg L9 , using same code on not brand phone (chinese clone) it works !! 
this phone has 2gb of ram instead lg l9 only 1gb, and version of android is different too. It could be hardware problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen a device that could support more than 4 concurrent active instances of VideoView (or meadia player, or stagefright, or OpenMAX). If your CPU is powerful enough, you should use a software solution (ffmpeg, or gstreamer).

Comment: I try using different phones and only LG not works, application crash since second stream.