# Videoview behavior on differents smartphone (with different stagefright)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, rtsp, stagefright

I'm having compatibility problems using videoview (or MediaPlayer) for play rtsp streams in multiple videoviews in the same activity.

I have opened another question on this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21111511/android-error-using-multiple-instance-of-videoview) but now I know that isn't my code the responsible, because I test same software on different phones and it work.

Viewing logcat Info messages for RTSP setup I see that each phone has different implementation of stagefright (android multimedia framework):

```
(A) I/RTSPEngine(147): User-Agent: Player/LG Player 1.0 for Android(stagefright alternative)
(B) I/ARTSPConnection(2252): User-Agent: stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 4.2.1)
(C) I/ARTSPConnection(10345): User-Agent: ALCATEL ONE TOUCH 997D-SVN/02001 (Linux;Android 4.1.1)
(D) W/ARTSPConnection(1948): User-Agent: User-Agent: Samsung GT-I9300 stagefright/Beyonce/1.1.9 (Linux;Android 4.3)


A is Lg l9 - android 4.1.2
B is Chinese jiayu g4 - Android 4.2.1
C is ALCATEL ONE TOUCH 997D - Android 4.1.1
D is Samsung galaxy S3 - Android 4.3
```

You can see that there are different android version and different stagefright here, but multiple rtsp fails only on Lg  (see error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21111511/android-error-using-multiple-instance-of-videoview) ). 
Another interesting thing is that only Lg use RtspEngine, others use ARTSPConnection

There is a way to force application to use native stagefright (if it exist on device) ?

How an application can manage this compatibility issue ? 
It is not reasonable to develop an app that will not be compatible with some brands of phones

Answer (score 3):

LG has full right to replace the AOSP implementation of RTSP with their engine. I don't have LG devices right now to test its performance and advantages (or disadvantages). Anyways, neither stagefright nor its alternatives were designed to support multiple concurrent active instances. I have never seen a device that would allow more than 4.

Luckily, with 1 GHz Dual-Core CPU (LG L9), you have enough generic computational power to decode four video streams of 270p, to fill the 960 x 540 screen, using ffmpeg, or gstreamer.

Comment: ok thanks, but Lg crash since second video stream (there is a bug ?), instead other test device are work at well on two and four streams.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the device cpu compatibility .Suggest you transplant decoding library ,like vlc, ffmpeg,or gstreamer.

Comment: cpu compatibility for what ?